# Probabilities calc

Tags: probability

over the past 10 years two golfers have had an ongoing battle as to who the best golfer is. Curtley Weird has won 120 of their 200 matches, while Dave Chilly has won 70 with 10 of them ending in ties. Because Dave is going overseas they decide to play a tournament of five matches to establish once and for all who the better player is . Find the probabilities that: (a) Dave wins at least three of the matches. (b) Curtley wins no more than two games. (c) All of the games end in a tie.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

For a) take the probabilities that dave will win at least 3 matches and sum them together eg $P$(Dave wins at least 3) = $P(WWWLL) + P(WWWWL) + P(WWWWW) + ...$

Can you do this? The trick is to cover all possible outcomes.